# RestSharp XmlSerializer Elements with Attributes and No Child Elements

Tags: attributes, xmlserializer, restsharp

Using RestSharp, How do i create an object that when serialized (XmlSerializer) creates the following XML? I.e. How do i serialize to create an XmlElement that has value AND an XmlAttribute.

```
<Person>
  <hair color="brown">true</hair> 
</Person>
```

The following seems to work for DeSerialization but not for Serialization

```
public class Person
{
    public Hair hair {get; set;}
}
public class Hair
{
    [SerializeAs(Attribute= true)]
    public String color {get; set;}
    public String Value {get; set;}
}
```